# Query one table where a column in that table contains a value from a column on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, one in each of two Microsoft SQL Server databases.

```
* DB 1 Table1.ID, Table1.Description, Table1.Comment
* DB 2 Table2.TriggerWord, Table2.Category
```

I want to query `Table1.Description` where the description contains a word from the `Table2.TriggerWord` table and return description, triggerword, category

I'd like it to be case insensitive, as the word description could have upper, lower, combo.

[Tables and Results Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJai3.jpg)

If I have to have the tables on the same database I can go that route.  Trying to avoid that as my source for table2 is already on a separate database.  Can't get this to work on the same database either.  I've tried a few ways and can't get it to return any results.

Tried this, but get no results:

```
SELECT        
    Table1.id, Table1.Description, Table2.TriggerWord, 
    Table2.Category
FROM            
    Table1, Table2
WHERE        
    (Table1.Description LIKE '%" & Table2.TriggerWord & "%')
```

It didn't error out, but no results based on the sample data in the picture.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: you don't really have double-quotes in your SQL, do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's best practice to join tables based on text like you're trying to do, but this might work for you:

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.Description, Table2.TriggerWord, Table2.Category
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Description LIKE '%'+ Table2.TriggerWord +'%'
```

Comment: This worked!  Happy to try a best practice though.  Is there an alternative approach that would work better?